# How to display a photo uploaded by user in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, display, photo-upload

I wanted to know how to display a photo that the user uploads on a website using html and javascript. I tried using code I found on another stackoverflow question but it didn't work for me. Here is the code I tried in chrome, firefox and safari. 
Any help is appreciated

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
    article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,menu, nav, section {
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(150)
                .height(200);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code works fine, however you have small problem which makes it not-working. It's easy to see if you debug your code.

Comment: Open the console and see if the action throws any error

Comment: thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below code snippet, I have tested it on Google chrome Version 66.0.3359.117 (Official Build) (64-bit) and it is working fine.

```js
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result).width(150).height(200);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
    <style>
        article,
        aside,
        figure,
        footer,
        header,
        hgroup,
        menu,
        nav,
        section {
            display: block;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use pure JS to get this working.

```js
function handleImageUpload() 
{

var image = document.getElementById("upload").files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      document.getElementById("display-image").src = e.target.result;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(image);

}
```

```html
<input id="upload" type="file" onChange="handleImageUpload()" />
<img id="display-image" src="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, I have tested it.

I think you forgot to link the javascript to your HTML source code.